# how to preserve the json array order in the response in REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot

how to preserve the json array order in the response value which came up in request body.

how to preserve the identifiers order in the response as well?

```
request
   

     --------  
          {
                "income": "xyz",
                "test": "1234",
                "identifiers": [{
                        "key": "test",
                        "value": 5678
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "test1",
                        "value": 1235
                    }
                ]
            
            }
    
response
--------  


{
        "income": "xyz",
        "test": "1234",
        "identifiers": [{
                "value": 5678,
                "key": "test"
                
            },
            {
               "value": 1235,
                "key": "test1"
                
            }
        ]
    
    }
```

Comment: Can you add more details about the problem ? please share some code as well if possible.

Comment: Did you try this annoation @JsonPropertyOrder({ "key", "value"})

Comment: simply we are getting the request ,and adding some items to list to the final response and showing to the user.

Comment: it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559459/preserving-order-in-java-object-to-json-with-spring-framework

Comment: The array is in its exact input order, the order of the keys of the object per array item differ, but that is of no importance.

Comment: in my case request and response classes will be automatically generated based upon on the json definition so cannot use @JsonPropertyOrder.

Comment: [`JSON parsing libraries have been observed to differ as to whether or not they make the ordering of object members visible to calling software. Implementations whose behavior does not depend on member ordering will be interoperable in the sense that they will not be affected by these differences.`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-4)